# How do I simplify fractions?

Tags: javascript, math

I've been working for awhile on a huge mathematical multitool and I'm making a fraction simplifier in it (all with alerts). I tried the following, what did I do wrong?

```js
if (confirm("Confirm to select a program\nCurrent program: Fraction Simplifier") == true) {
    var numerator = prompt("Enter the numerator");
    var denominator = prompt("Enter the denominator");
    var nFrac = numerator;
    var dFrac = denominator;
    simpFrac();
    alert(numerator + "/" + denominator + " simplified is " + nFrac + "/" + dFrac);
};
function simpFrac() {
    for (var i = 1; i < dFrac; i++) {
        fracV = fracV + 1;
        if (Number.isInteger(nFrac / fracV) && Number.isInteger(dFrac / fracV)) {
          nFrac = nFrac / fracV;
          dFrac = dFrac / fracV;  
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: You forgot to explain the _Problem_ you're having with this code.

Comment: Adding parameters to `simpFrac` instead of using globals is advisable.

Comment: Check the console. _"Uncaught ReferenceError: fracV is not defined",_

Comment: My JS is a bit rusty, byut I;m guessing you need a `let fracV;` as first line in your simpFrac

Comment: Also, please use full names: `simpFrac` -> `simplifyFraction`. Better names are always good. You dont have to pay per byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the numerator and the denominator by the GCD.

```js
const GCD = (a, b) => b ? GCD(b, a % b) : a;
let numerator = 15, denominator = 18;
let div = GCD(numerator, denominator);
console.log(`${numerator}/${denominator} simplifies to ${numerator/div}/${denominator/div}`);
```

Comment: not that simple

Comment: While this might or might not work, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @epascarello So much for that...

Comment: @tadman Why not?

Comment: @epascarello Do you have an example?

Comment: @epascarello: How is not that simple?

Answer (score 1):

someone answered and deleted their answer, I implemented their method. It worked.
Changed to

```
if (confirm("Confirm to select a program\nCurrent program: Fraction Simplifier") == true) {
    if (confirm("Confirm to select a program\nCurrent program: Fraction Simplifier") == true) {
    var numerator = prompt("Enter the numerator");
    var denominator = prompt("Enter the denominator");
    var GCD = (a, b) => b ? GCD(b, a % b) : a;
    let div = GCD(numerator, denominator);
    alert(numerator + "/" + denominator + " simplifies to " + numerator / div + "/" + denominator / div + ".");
```

Comment: Glad to see my answer helped.

Comment: @Unmitigated, ah that confused me.

Comment: strange, answer disappeared on my pov and now its back